# Bitbucker pipeline self hosted runner ID retrival

Tags: git, docker, continuous-integration, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

is there any any variable to retrieve self-hosted runner ID in bitbucket pipeline like any variable as it keeps changing everytime I build and I want to use it in pipeline.

someone else has setup the runner. So, I have no idea how the runner is setup. But I can only see the runner ID in logs and can't find any variable to retrieve it.

Any kind of help would be appreciated!

variable to retrieve self-hosted runner ID in bitbucket.

Comment: There is no variable about that https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/variables-and-secrets/ . My question would be, why would you care about the runner id? If you used a shared runner instead of a self-hosted one, what worth would be knowing the runner id?